# Does additional license required to install Snow Leopard into Parallels VM?

Tags: macos, license, parallels

I have an iMac and an Snow Leopard license.
I'm planning using Parallels to make additional virtual Mac. (for test and debugging purpose)
Do I have to buy additional Snow Leopard license for the VMs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question on StackOverflow discusses the legality of running OSX in a VM:

- [Is it possible to run OSX in a virtual machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39159/is-it-possible-to-run-osx-in-a-virtual-machine)

Comment: Thanks. "License is single use only." I should buy additional license for VM.

Comment: You need to buy a license for the Server version. Parallels and VMWare won't let you install OS X client to a VM.

Comment: Oh really? Server version only (legally)? If so, I have to give up all my plans. Main purpose of VM was making a (cheap) OS X sandbox.

Comment: Snow Leopard Server is currently the only version of OS X that is licensed for virtualization.